# How to change theme colours in a run-time

Tags: android, css, customization, mobile-development

I am currently working on a remote styling feature. Cannot find a way how to change `colorPrimary` value after the activity is created and the remote style is downloaded via the API. I know that the theme styling is immutable and that value cannot be changed, but I believe there is a way to to tell all the Material components, status bar and menu bar to use a specific colours after is it ready to use. Any ideas?

Attaching my theme code:

```
<style name="OrderingTheme" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
 </style>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change theme color at runtime because Themes are not mutable. But you can change StatusBar color with `Window.setStatusBarColor()`. and also you can change navigation bar color with `Window.setNavigationBarColor()`.
But if you would have to You can assign one color to a variable and on switching mode/color/theme you can switch the color assigned to that variable.

Comment: I know that, my concern is more about material components, instead of changing every single one, changing colorPrimary would change all the views immediately